# Using JsonCPP ValueIterator with STL algorithms

Tags: c++, boost, jsoncpp, boost-iterators, iterator-facade

I know, `ValueIterator` from JsonCPP cannot be used in standard STL algorithms directly. But
is there a some "indirect" way to use it in STL algorithms (maybe via *Boost.Iterator* or something like this)? I want something likes to following:

```
Json::Value root = getJson(); //came from outside
std::vector<Json::Value> vec;

std::copy
  ( make_some_smart_iterator(...) // some iterator produced with start of root
  , make_some_smart_iterator(...) // some iterator produced with end of root
  , std::back_inserter(vec)
  );
```

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to write some kind of iterator wrapper type, e.g. use `boost::iterator_facade` or derive from `std::iterator`.

Comment: @NateKohl - I agree. Other considering options are `boost::function_input_iterator` or `boost::iterator_adaptor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a custom iterator derived from `boost::iterator_facade`.

```
#include <boost/iterator/iterator_facade.hpp>

class JsonIter : public boost::iterator_facade
     <JsonIter, Json::ValueIterator, boost::forward_traversal_tag, Json::Value &>
{
public:
    JsonIter() {}
    explicit JsonIter(Json::ValueIterator iter) : m_iter(iter) {}
private:
    friend class boost::iterator_core_access;

    void increment() { ++m_iter; }
    bool equal(const JsonIter &other) const {return this->m_iter == other.m_iter;}
    Json::Value &dereference() const { return *m_iter; }
    Json::ValueIterator m_iter;
};
```

And client code is following:

```
std::copy(JsonIter(root.begin()), JsonIter(root.end()), std::back_inserter(vec));
```